# Create Algorithm Undefined User Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql

I had no problem at all running the following code on a local server, but when I run it from phpMyAdmin on a Yahoo hosting webserver, I am getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFI

Here's the code:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `users` AS select `tblusers`.`id` AS `id`,`tblusers`.`password` AS `password`,`tblusers`.`title` AS `title`,`tblusers`.`first` AS `first`,`tblusers`.`last` AS `last`,`tblusers`.`gender` AS `gender`,`tblusers`.`address` AS `address`,`tblusers`.`address_2` AS `address_2`,`tblusers`.`city` AS `city`,`tblusers`.`state` AS `state`,`tblusers`.`postcode` AS `postcode`,`tblusers`.`country` AS `country`,`tblusers`.`email` AS `email`,`tblusers`.`emailnotes` AS `emailnotes`,`tblusers`.`Home_Phone` AS `Home_Phone`,`tblusers`.`Office_Phone` AS `Office_Phone`,`tblusers`.`Cell_Phone` AS `Cell_Phone`,`tblusers`.`Contact_Preference` AS `Contact_Preference`,`tblusers`.`Birthdate` AS `Birthdate`,`tblusers`.`Age` AS `Age`,`tblusers`.`Marital_Status` AS `Marital_Status`,`tblusers`.`Children` AS `Children`,`tblusers`.`occupation` AS `occupation`,`tblusers`.`HebrewName` AS `HebrewName`,`tblusers`.`notes` AS `notes`,`tblusers`.`Feedback` AS `Feedback`,`tblusers`.`date_submitted` AS `date_submitted`,`tblusers`.`DateCalled` AS `DateCalled`,`tblusers`.`last_contact` AS `last_contact`,`tblusers`.`Calling_Card` AS `Calling_Card`,`tbluserstudent`.`student_user_id` AS `student_user_id`,`tbluserstudent`.`LearningBackground` AS `LearningBackground`,`tbluserstudent`.`Affiliation` AS `Affiliation`,`tbluserstudent`.`education` AS `education`,`tbluserstudent`.`Preferred_Level` AS `Preferred_Level`,`tbluserstudent`.`Community` AS `Community`,`tbluserstudent`.`religious_observance` AS `religious_observance`,`tbluserstudent`.`jewish_identity` AS `jewish_identity`,`tbluserstudent`.`mother_jewish_identity` AS `mother_jewish_identity`,`tbluserstudent`.`father_jewish_identity` AS `father_jewish_identity`,`tbluserstudent`.`NotJewish` AS `NotJewish`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`student_teacher_user_id` AS `student_teacher_user_id`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`preferred_language` AS `preferred_language`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`language_other` AS `language_other`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`language_fluency` AS `language_fluency`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`2nd_language` AS `2nd_language`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`2nd_language_other` AS `2nd_language_other`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`2nd_language_fluency` AS `2nd_language_fluency`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`hebrew` AS `hebrew`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`text_discussion` AS `text_discussion`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`HeardOf` AS `HeardOf`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`skype_ID` AS `skype_ID`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`headset` AS `headset`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`webcam` AS `webcam`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`NewSystem` AS `NewSystem`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`Matchable` AS `Matchable`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`LA` AS `LA`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`WeeklyReminder` AS `WeeklyReminder`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`special` AS `special`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`NotInterested` AS `NotInterested`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`subject` AS `subject`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`studytimes` AS `studytimes`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`RefFirst` AS `RefFirst`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`RefLast` AS `RefLast`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`RefPhone` AS `RefPhone`,`tbluserstudentteacher`.`RefNotes` AS `RefNotes`,`tbluserteacher`.`teacher_user_id` AS `teacher_user_id`,`tbluserteacher`.`origin` AS `origin`,`tbluserteacher`.`teach_education` AS `teach_education`,`tbluserteacher`.`education_other` AS `education_other`,`tbluserteacher`.`teaching_experience` AS `teaching_experience`,`tbluserteacher`.`teaching_experience_other` AS `teaching_experience_other`,`tbluserteacher`.`teacher_Preferred_Level` AS `teacher_Preferred_Level`,`tblusershliach`.`shliach_user_id` AS `shliach_user_id`,`tblusershliach`.`Mosad` AS `Mosad`,`tblusershliach`.`Shlucha` AS `Shlucha`,`tblusershliach`.`ShluchaPhone` AS `ShluchaPhone`,`tblusershliach`.`ShluchaEmail` AS `ShluchaEmail`,`tblusershliach`.`invited` AS `invited`,`tblusershliach`.`Contacted` AS `Contacted`,`tblusershliach`.`Wants` AS `Wants`,`tblusershliach`.`web` AS `web`,`tblusershliach`.`sent` AS `sent`,`tblusershliach`.`feed` AS `feed`,`tblusershliach`.`MailingDate` AS `MailingDate`,`tblusershliach`.`Students` AS `Students` from ((((`tblusers` left join `tbluserstudent` on((`tblusers`.`id` = `tbluserstudent`.`student_user_id`))) left join `tbluserstudentteacher` on((`tblusers`.`id` = `tbluserstudentteacher`.`student_teacher_user_id`))) left join `tbluserteacher` on((`tblusers`.`id` = `tbluserteacher`.`teacher_user_id`))) left join `tblusershliach` on((`tblusers`.`id` = `tblusershliach`.`shliach_user_id`)));
```

Why am I getting this error on a webserver but not locally?

Comment: What are the versions of each server?

Comment: the local one is wampserver 2.0, while the myphp is version   4.1.14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL 4.1.14 did not support `ALGORITHM`s.  You won't be able to run this query on your Yahoo! host unless they have an option to use MySQL 5, which introduced this new feature.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a different MySQL version or a different storage engine or different configuration?

Anyway, you can simply omit 'ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED'.